# When Switching Orientation with an Android App that uses a Timer, how to I keep the original timer active?

Tags: android, timer, android-orientation

I am writing an App that uses the Timer process to display a time countdown and total time on the screen.  This means I have at least two textviews, one for leg time, one for total time that should display a changing value (down) as seconds pass.

The "timer" is set up this way:

```
    Handler timerHandler = new Handler();
Runnable timerRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        // do something here to display

        processTime();    // process what to be done on a sec by sec basis
        timerHandler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
    }
};
```

There is a button on the screen to start the process and this is the code that starts the timer:

```
    private ImageButton.OnClickListener onClick_btnStartPlan = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // this will begin the actual running of the plan.  It kicks off the timer
        // which also kicks off the gps location listener

        if (currentPlan.size() != 0) {
            setActionButtons(getString(R.string.startButtonPushed));  // reset back to just the play if we stopped the plan
            startLocationUpdates();
            timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 0);
        }

    }
};
```

When I first start the program I execute a function in the onCreate event that sets up my listeners:

```
    private void setActivityMainListeners() {
    Log.i(eTAG, "setActivityMainListeners function 1");
    txtPace = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtAvgPace);

    TextView txt1 = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.txtAvgPace));
    txt1.setText(" ");
    TextView txt2 = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.txtLegTime));
    txt2.setText(" ");
    TextView txt3 = (TextView) findViewById((R.id.txtTotalTime));
    txt3.setText(" ");

    ImageButton btnCreatePlan = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnManagePlans);
    btnCreatePlan.setOnClickListener(onClick_btnCreatePlans);
    ImageButton btnSelectPlan = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnOpenPlan);
    btnSelectPlan.setOnClickListener(onClick_btnOpenPlan);
    ImageButton btnStartPlan = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnStartPlan);
    btnStartPlan.setOnClickListener(onClick_btnStartPlan);
    ImageButton btnPausePlan = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnPausePlan);
    btnPausePlan.setOnClickListener(onClick_btnPausePlan);
    ImageButton btnStopPlan = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnStopPlan);
    btnStopPlan.setOnClickListener(onClick_btnStopPlan);

    createLocationRequest();

    if (!openSession) {
        LinearLayout btnActions = (LinearLayout) findViewById((R.id.lyActionButtons));
        btnActions.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }

    // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
    // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
    client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

}
```

All of this worked fine before I added the ability to switch orientation.  However, I decided to add a landscape View and when I did I learned the hard way about needing to save State.  SO I researched and added this code:

```
    @Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    Log.i(eTAG, "onSaveInstanceState");
    outState.putLong(SAVE_TOTAL_TIME,planTime);
    outState.putString(SAVE_LEG_GAIT,legGait);
    outState.putInt(SAVE_LEG_NUMBER,legNumber);
    outState.putLong(SAVE_LEG_TIME,legTime);
    outState.putBoolean(SAVE_OPEN_SESSION,openSession);
    outState.putStringArrayList(SAVE_CURRENT_PLAN,currentPlan);

}

@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    Log.i(eTAG, "onRestoreInstanceState");
    planTime = savedInstanceState.getLong(SAVE_TOTAL_TIME);
    legGait = savedInstanceState.getString(SAVE_LEG_GAIT);
    legNumber = savedInstanceState.getInt(SAVE_LEG_NUMBER);
    legTime = savedInstanceState.getLong(SAVE_LEG_TIME);
    openSession = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SAVE_OPEN_SESSION);
    currentPlan = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList(SAVE_CURRENT_PLAN);

}
```

and modified my onCreate to be aware of a change and reset some values:

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Log.i(eTAG, "onCreate");

    setTitle(R.string.activityMainTitle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_track_it_eq_display);

    // First we need to check availability of play services
    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        Log.i(eTAG, "passed check services");
        // Building the GoogleApi client
        // buildGoogleApiClient();
    }
    setUpGoogleApiClientIfNeeded();
    createLocationRequest();


    setActivityMainListeners();  // set the various handers for the display
    soundStuff();          // Load the sounds and sound processing
    client2 = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {

        Log.i(eTAG, "onCreate orientation change");
        planTime = savedInstanceState.getLong(SAVE_TOTAL_TIME);
        legGait = savedInstanceState.getString(SAVE_LEG_GAIT);
        legNumber = savedInstanceState.getInt(SAVE_LEG_NUMBER);
        legTime = savedInstanceState.getLong(SAVE_LEG_TIME);
        openSession = savedInstanceState.getBoolean(SAVE_OPEN_SESSION);
        TextView legText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLegTime);
        TextView totText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTotalTime);
        totText.setText(displayTime(planTime));
        legText.setText(String.format("%1s %2s", gaitLetter(legGait), displayTime(legTime)));
        if (openSession) {
            LinearLayout btnActions = (LinearLayout) findViewById((R.id.lyActionButtons));
            btnActions.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            setActionButtons(getString(R.string.startButtonPushed));
        }
    }

}
```

Now, when I change the orientation of the screen the two time textviews will show a value, but now the value is frozen even though though log entries I can see that the timer is still running.

I did read up on the issue of orientation and how you need to save data and repost on restore or the onCreate of the switch.  What I do not understand is what happens to the timer of what happens to the View such that I know something is going on in the program, but no change occurs on the screen.

This is the function to should display data to the textviews

```
    private void setLegDisplay() {
    Log.i(eTAG, "setLegDisplay");
    Log.i(eTAG, "    planTime:" + planTime);
    Log.i(eTAG, "    legGait:" + legGait);
    Log.i(eTAG, "    legNumber:" + legNumber);
    Log.i(eTAG, "    legTime:" + legTime);
    Log.i(eTAG, "    openSession:" + openSession);
    TextView legText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLegTime);
    TextView totText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtTotalTime);
    totText.setText(displayTime(planTime));
    legText.setText(String.format("%1s %2s", gaitLetter(legGait), displayTime(legTime)));

}
```

Is a second timer getting created and if so, how can I make sure I keep the original timer in the switch as it is still running?

Thank you for any help on this question.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the previous runnable callbacks in `onDestroy();` before the orientation is changed.

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
    }
```

Comment: For now I went with this approach.  I had to add a switch that indicated the timer needed to restarted since it is originally started with a button tap.  Thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you should right a service which runs the timer.Let the activity communicate with the service and get the timer values. This will free you from hassles of maintaining the state on configuration change.

Comment: I did not know anything about services so I didn't try this approach for now.  However, as I began reading it does seem to the the more elegant approach.

From what I gather, the service runs independent of the UI Activity so it is not affected by the orientation change and its destroy/create actions.  I do need to figure out how to implement a start/stop process since the app allows a user the ability to start, pause, and stop the timer.  If I get it working I'll post the code here for anyone else looking for a simple solution.